# Laravel 8: InvalidArgumentException View [auth.login] not found

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I am trying to redirect the unauthorized user to login page. But the problem is i delete the auth folder in the view, it redirect me to the auth.login page. I want to redirect me to the local host main URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/).
How to resolve it?

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Auth::routes();


Route::prefix('/admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function () {

    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class, 'login']);
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController::class, 'dashboard']);
    });
});


Route::namespace('Front')->group(function () {
    //Home Page Route
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\IndexController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\IndexController::class, 'userlogin']);
    Route::get('userRegister', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\IndexController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('user-register', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\IndexController::class, 'userRegister']);

    // Middleware
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'studentdashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\IndexController::class, 'dashboard']);
        Route::get('studentlogout', [App\Http\Controllers\Front\IndexController::class, 'logout']);
    });
});
```

- When unauthorized user trying to access the files the system should redirect the to IndexController login function

Answer (score 0):

just edit `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
  //if unautorized
    if ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

 //or if path/file is not found:
  if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

dont forget to use the classes:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
```

or if you have custom auth middleware you can add that on you middleware too

Comment: on return parent::render($request, $e); it gives an error Cannot use 'parent' in a class with no parent.